# VueFire vs Vue.js + Node.js vs Vue.js + Feathers advantages, disadvantages and differences

Tags: node.js, firebase, vuejs2, feathersjs, vuefire

I have doing a lot of research about frontend frameworks and have decided that I would like to try Vue.js. However, I would also like to get a backend with real time "data updating". I have looked at VueFire (Vue.js + Firebase), Node.js and Feathers. It looks like Feathers has a limited amount of resources/documentation on using it with Vue while there seems to be a good amount of information on VueFire and Node.js with Vue.js.

What are the differences between those three backends? 
What are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

> What are the differences between those three backends?

Let's clarify a few things.

- Node.js is, as defined on their website: "*a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.*"
- Firebase is a platform as a service (PaaS).
- Feathers is REST and realtime API framework, a back-end framework.
- VueFire is just a wrapper around the Firebase JS SDK. It makes calling Firebase more "Vue" like.
- Vue.js is a front-end framework or progressive framework as the creator calls it.

With that said we're comparing Feathers and Firebase. It's clear what the difference is and the advantages/disadvantages.

> What are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Firebase lets you hit the ground running. You create your Firebase account/project and you're set to go with all the [products](https://firebase.google.com/products/) it offers. You do not have to worry about setting up your own database layer, authentication/security, or anything. It's all set up and managed for you, but at a [cost](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). Besides the money factor, you've also locked yourself and depend heavy on a third party and [things can change at anytime without any say in the matter.](https://startupsventurecapital.com/firebase-costs-increased-by-7-000-81dc0a27271d)

Feathers is a framework. It gives to tools to create your own Firebase platform. You're free to configure it however you want. You're in full control and it's free. However, you will have to setup your own database layer, security, and likely more.

In the end it boils down to your needs/requirements. It's best to make a list of your specific needs and see what framework or service fulfills those needs. It's **useless** to search for advantages/disadvantages as you will get opinion-based answers.

Comment: I think I messed up with some namings on the Node.js part. What I meant was using Express for the backend and have that communicate with for example MongoDB and receive/send requests from/to the Vue.js frontend and use socket.io for real time updates. But as far as I have understood Express "runs" on Node.js? Thank you for the detailed answer, I will try to go over my requirements and see what fits.